# Does hatred protect us and make us strong?

Tags: catholicism, hate

God is love, but, can't hatred be good and necessary in some cases?

What does the catholic church say about hate?

Hate can make you stronger, because it can be a motivation to do something, to defend yourself from something or simply to help you on the path of life to not let yourself be trampled on.

Comment: It is right to hate sin and to hate injustice, but I don't see how that would make us strong. Can you [edit] this to explain what you were thinking of?

Comment: @curiousdannii Done!

Comment: Too short for an answer, here is a nice quote of Alcuin, from his dialogue with Charlemagne: "Clemency is the power used by a forgiving spirit to hold in check its hatred and its sense of injury."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Short answer**

Yes, God is love.  Yes, God and Jesus hate evil.  Yes, overcoming evil is why Jesus came.  But in our actions, like Jesus, Christians should **NOT** be driven by hate but empowered with **love**.  For strength, you may have been thinking of **anger**, an irascible passion that can be in the service of both good and evil action (see the analysis below).

**Detailed answer**

In Catholicism, using the [Thomistic analysis of the human action](https://aquinas101.thomisticinstitute.org/human-acts), while hatred (being one of the 6 [concupiscible appetite](https://www.newadvent.org/cathen/11534a.htm)) can be a *cause* of an action aroused by evil **it's not hatred that makes you stronger, but a combination of**:

- [Hope](https://www.newadvent.org/cathen/07465b.htm): to **be daring** and to avoid despair, useful while making a **decision** to take action; one of the 3 [theological virtues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theological_virtues)
- [Courage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Courage): to **overcome fear** while **executing** the action; one of the [4 cardinal virtues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_virtues)
- Anger: to **add resolve** in overcoming present evil while **executing** the action; one of the 5 [irascible passions](https://www.newadvent.org/cathen/11534a.htm)

which plug into appropriate stages in the [Process of Human Action](https://aquinas101.thomisticinstitute.org/human-acts):
[image: Process of Human Action]

#### Resources

- [Concise descriptions of each of the 11 passions](https://www3.nd.edu/%7Eafreddos/courses/406/passitax.htm) by Notre Dame Thomist expert and professor: [Alfred J. Freddoso](https://www3.nd.edu/%7Eafreddos/)
- Aquinas 101 topical videos

  - [Fortitude](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BDOiDT_awxM): discusses Courage and its relation with fear
  - [Hope](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gNIYLIr_nkM) : discusses Hope and its relation with beatitude
- Aquinas 101 [Course 4: Principles of the Moral Life](https://aquinas101.thomisticinstitute.org/principles-of-the-moral-life):

  - [Episode 49: Human Action](https://aquinas101.thomisticinstitute.org/human-acts)
  - [Episode 51: The Passions in General](https://aquinas101.thomisticinstitute.org/passions-of-the-soul) placing hate and love in the context of other passions as well as *for* another person
  - [Episode 52: The Specific Passions](https://aquinas101.thomisticinstitute.org/the-specific-passions) explaining hope (as passion), anger, etc.
  - [Episode 54: Virtue](https://aquinas101.thomisticinstitute.org/virtues) explaining the 4 cardinal virtues, including courage
- Peter King's book chapter [Aquinas on the Passions](http://individual.utoronto.ca/pking/articles/Aquinas_on_the_Passions.pdf) in [Aquinas's Moral Theory](https://www.amazon.ca/Aquinass-Moral-Theory-Kretzmann-1999-04-29/dp/B01JXOU1XE) (Cornell, 1999)
- Peter King's book chapter [Emotions](http://individual.utoronto.ca/pking/articles/Aquinas_on_the_Emotions.pdf) in [Oxford Handbook of Aquinas](https://www.oxfordhandbooks.com/view/10.1093/oxfordhb/9780195326093.001.0001/oxfordhb-9780195326093) (2012)

Comment: Thank you, you are totally right! God bless you.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the irascible appetites.

Comment: @Geremia The Aquinas 101 episodes turns out to be **really** good for someone new to Aquinas (especially Episode 51).  After watching them I'll update the answer some more, showing how hate, love, anger, hope (as passion), daring, hope (as virtue) and courage relates to each other.